# Unable to render array of objects in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have array of objects in React-Native that look like this in console

```
[{
  "isDonor": true,
  "name": "Nadi",
  "photo": "https://gre",
  "uid": "2ZE"
}, {
  "email": "mmaz",
  "isDonor": true,
  "name": "Mz",
  "photo": "https://gra",
  "uid": "Cb"
}]
```

but when i render it i get notthing on screen here is code

```
{donorsData.map((v, i) => {return <Text key={i}>{v.name}</Text>;})}
```

I'm trying to render each object on screen with it's properties

Comment: Looks good to me. Could you publish full code for the component or better create a [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/)?

Comment: If nothing renders, very probably, your code is not even executed.

Comment: @Nishant here is the snack. just render objects on screen 
[link](https://snack.expo.io/@bilefif4/objec)

Comment: Can you add the snack to your question? I fear it might be closed otherwise.

Comment: @AqsaMaan The snack is not even using `donorsData` variable. Please update it to show the problem.

Comment: with this code `<Button title="get date"onPress={() =>alert(donorsData.map((v, i) => {return v.name;}),)}/>` I'm getting both names on objects. how can i reder them one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks perfect, it should render the data without any problem, but still here is the full working example:

**Working App: [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/brave-croissant)**

[image]

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

const donorsData = [
  {
    isDonor: true,
    name: 'Nadi',
    photo: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8vJf.jpg?s=328&g=1',
    uid: '2ZE',
    email: 'nadi@test.com',
  },
  {
    email: 'mz@test.com',
    isDonor: true,
    name: 'Mz',
    photo: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8vJf.jpg?s=328&g=1',
    uid: 'Cb',
  },
];
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {donorsData.map((v, i) => {
        return (
          <View
            key={v.uid}
            style={{
              backgroundColor: 'white',
              padding: 10,
              margin: 5,
              borderRadius: 10,
            }}>
            <Text>{v.name}</Text>
            <Text>{v.email}</Text>
            <Image source={{ uri: v.photo }} style={{ height: 150, flex: 1 }} />
          </View>
        );
      })}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

Comment: Yes it's working on snack, but its not working on emulator or real device. further more I want to render all objects with their properties in differnent `View`. How to do that?

Comment: But if i use it like this `<Button title="get date"onPress={() =>alert(donorsData.map((v, i) => {return v.name;}),)}/>` then I'm getting both names in `alert`

Comment: Updated the code to render all the data in one card. And it does render on emulator.

Comment: "But if i use it like this <Button title="get date"onPress={() =>alert(donorsData.map((v, i) => {return v.name;}),)}/> then I'm getting both names in alert", can't comment without looking at your whole code.

Comment: It works when data is stored in object like u did. but i'm getting data from firebase and which then it doesn't work

Comment: Use conditional rendering, if data exists then render the corresponding component else don't. and also, specify your entire problem statement beforehand, it saves time.

Comment: data already exists so why should i use condition? sorry about that I'm new to programming

Comment: When you fetch data from any remote server, like firebase or remote API, it gets fetched asynchronously, before they are fetched you will have no data to render, so in that time conditional rending is used. And about your repo, I would have gone through it to fix it but setting it up on expo will take up a lot of time so I am giving it a skip. If you set it up on expo then let me know.

Comment: can u please give example how to implement condition? I have tried but failed to do so. @KetanRamteke

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap your required data into View and give style to it.

```
return (
   <View style={styles.container}>
{donorsData.map((v, i) => {
return <View> 
<Text key={i}>{v.name}</Text>
</View>;
})}
```

);